# Why does repeating setLabel() in SWING cause out of memory?

Tags: java, swing, awt

The class variables are like this:

```
Button[] tab_but = new Button[440];
static int ii;
```

After initializing tab_but, I'm testing the following job.

```
for (int j = 0; j < 9999; j++) {
  String newLabel = String.valueOf(ii);

  for (int i = 0; i < 440; i++) {
    tab_but[i].setLabel(newLabel);
  }

  ii += 1;
}
```

And it gets 'out of memory' finally.

As I profiled it, Object [] allocation was increasing rapidly with running it.

I think I did only replacing the label, so the previous label object(String) should be cleaned. right?

Why does that kind of memory leak occur?

Please advise and thanks.

Comment: This is not a SWING problem since you are using `Button` (not `JButton`) which is an AWT widget. Besides, I don't understand why you loop 9999 times, since in the end, all buttons will have the last `ii` as their label.

Comment: Do wou observe the same behavior if you repalce Button with JButton (which I would advise anyway because you probably don't want to mix AWT with Swing).

Answer (score 3):

I strongly suspect there's something you haven't shown us here. 10000 strings is *nothing* in terms of memory. If each string is, say, 64 bytes (and that's almost certainly larger than reality) then those 10000 strings take up 640K. I'm assuming you have rather more memory than that, and you haven't set the maximum heap size to something tiny?

Could you provide a short but *complete* program which demonstrates the problem here?

I wonder whether it's not the *strings* which are causing the problem, but the fact that you've got 4.4 million UI events being generated - and because you're never letting the UI handle them, they're all building up with no way of them getting cleared. That would make rather more sense (even though it's still not *that* many objects) - but I'm unsure why you'd see this in real life - obviously the example you've given isn't a particularly realistic one, and you must have come up with it having run out of memory in a more normal program...

Comment: OK, I know it's abnormal case - not realistic. And other part of code is very usual - just making UI and assigning handler. Only above part is problem. Changing newLabel to some string constant removes the problem. So, is there special way to handle or clear event queue?

Comment: @JaycePark: So how did you come up with it, out of interest. I don't know the details of Swing's UI loop, but presumably the setLabel call is basically adding a deferred action (e.g. to invalidate an area). It's still just a guess, but it's the only one that makes sense to me.

Comment: +1 very nice and clear answer. To be honest myself I would also be interested in seeing an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) presenting the issue. As it sounds unbelievable to me that only so few strings would cause this problem.

Comment: @Boro: I suspect we could reproduce the same issue with just two string values and one label - toggle a single label between two states *lots* of times to generate the same huge number of refresh events etc.

Comment: @Jon Skeet I tried to the OP's code, in/out/before/after invokeLater, with the buttons added/not added to content of a frame, to method just to make sure it is not related to it. Still the same result no exception. I would suspect that there is actually something else that is buggy in the code.

Comment: @Boro: Could be. Did you have any listeners attached to the buttons? That may affect things. As you say, a short but complete program would really help...

Comment: @Jon Skeet the only nasty thing I achieved is as you mentioned by adding the action listeners and modifying the buttons after the frame is shown. Now the buttons are still counting, each is at 5000 at the moment. And there is lots of flickering.

Answer (score 0):

I believe when you do the `String new Label = String.valueOf(ii);`you're creating a new string.  When you assign it to the label with `setLabel()`, there's a reference saved that's overwritten the next time around.  Thus, a memory leak.

Comment: Technically it's not a *leak*. The GC just hasn't been run before he exhausts the available memory.

Comment: Does `String` use `Object[]` mentioned in the question? Is JVM allowed to throw OOM without attempting GC first?

Answer (score 0):

The garbage collector in Java isn't instant. When there are no more references to an object it becomes *available* to be garbage collected.

You're creating (and discarding) 9999 `String` objects. You're running out of memory before they can be collected.

Comment: I don't believe this is the case - 10,000 short strings is *nothing* to a JVM of any normal size. See my answer for an alternative explanation.